# Regular Expression replacement to convert Less mixins to Scss

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking to convert Less mixin calls to their equivalents in Scss:

1. `.mixin();` should become `@mixin();`
2. `.mixin(0);` should become `@mixin(0);`
3. `.mixin(0; 1; 2);` should become `@mixin(0, 1, 2);`

I'm having the most difficulty with the third example, as I essentially need to match `n` groups separated by semicolons, and replace those with the same groups separated by commas. I suppose this relies on some sort of repeating groups functionality in regexes that I'm not familiar with.

It's not simply enough to simply replace semicolons within paren - I need a regex that will only match the `\.[\w\-]+\(.*\)` format of mixins, but obviously with some magic in the second match group to handle the 3rd example above.

I'm doing this in Ruby, so if you're able to provide replacement syntax that's compatible with `gsub`, that would be awesome. **I would like a single regex replacement, something that doesn't require multiple passes to clean up the semicolons.**

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. Is there not a way to do this without two passes through gsub?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding two capturing groups round the subvalues you need and using an additional `gsub` in the first `gsub` block to replace the `;` with `,` only in the 2nd group.

See

```
s = ".mixin(0; 1; 2);"
puts s.gsub(/\.([\w\-]+)(\(.*\))/) { "##{$1}#{$2.gsub(/;/, ',')}" }
# => #mixin(0, 1, 2);
```

The pattern details:

- `\.` - a literal dot
- `([\w\-]+)`  - Group 1 capturing 1 or more word chars (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or `-`
- `(\(.*\))` - Group 2 capturing a `(`, then any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols as many as possible up to the last `)` and the last `)`. **NOTE**: if there are multiple values, use *lazy matching* - `(\(.*?\))`  - here.

Comment: Also, see [this online demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUkFROTlJbmVjTTA). Also, to support the *balanced* parentheses in Group 2, you might want to change the Group 2 pattern to `(\((?:[^()]++|\g<2>)*\))`. See [this Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/mXy2sEpnyV).

Comment: Your answer i think is the closest one,but  there is something wrong here,
"mixin" is a keyword in sass(output), not less(input).
the word "mixin" in the input could be of any value.
But the output MUST contain the keyword @mixin.

Comment: And the mixin in the output begins with "@" not "#"

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
less_style = ".mixin(0; 1; 2);"

# convert the first period to @
less_style.gsub! /^\./, '@'

# convert the inner semicolons to commas
scss_style = less_style.gsub /(?<=[\(\d]);/, ','

scss_style
# => "@mixin(0, 1, 2);"
```

The second regex is using positive lookbehinds. You can read about those here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

I also use this neat web app to play around with regexes: http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a single pass through gsub:

```
".mixin(0; 1; 2);".gsub(/(?<!\));|\./, ";" => ",", "." => "@")
 => "@mixin(0, 1, 2);"
```

It's an OR regex with a hash for the replacement parameters.

Assuming from your example that you just want to replace semicolons not following close parens(negative lookbehind): `(?<!\));`

You can modify/build on this with other expressions. Even add more OR conditions to the regex.

Also, you can use the block version of gsub if you need more options.